# Replacing the FileService Api to create a Blob file in server side

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, google-cloud-storage, blobstore

I am using the FileService Api to save files to the Blobstore from server side like this:

```
    FileService fileService = FileServiceFactory.getFileService();
    AppEngineFile file = null;
    file = fileService.createNewBlobFile(contentType, fileName);

    boolean lock = true;
    FileWriteChannel writeChannel = null;
    writeChannel = fileService.openWriteChannel(file, lock);

    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(FILE_BYTES);
    writeChannel.write(bb);
    writeChannel.closeFinally();
    BlobKey blobKey = fileService.getBlobKey(file);
    return blobKey.getKeyString();
```

But the FileService Api is going out by July this year (2015) [File Api Service Turndown](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/deprecations/files_api).

I am searching for an alternative to do this. I need to create a file from a byte[] in server side and save it to the blobstore.

I know and use the *createUploadUrl* option to upload and save files to the blobstore from client side

```
    BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();
    url = blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/upload", uploadOptions);
```

But what I need is to create and save files right in the server side, as the FileService Api do/did.

I have searched the migration documents for [JAVA](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/files_api_migration) and there is no alternative for this. The only option is via POST with the *createUploadUrl*

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the Blobstore is near to the permanent shutdown, you need to starts using Google Cloud Storage.

The [Google Cloud Storage Client Library](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlecloudstorageclient/download) is fully integrated for App Engine, making easy the migration to another API.

After you saved an object to Cloud Storage, you can generated a BlobKey starting from the object name.

```
GcsFilename gcs_file = /* your uploaded file */;
String cloudStorageURL = "/gs/" + gcs_file.getBucketName() + "/" + gcs_file.getObjectName();
BlobstoreService bs = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();
return bs.createGsBlobKey(cloudStorageURL);
```

In this way you don't need to alter your entire code (and possibly the datastore) because you keep using a BlobKey object as a file identifier.